# Has anyone found a Dreamweaver code collapse plugin?

Tags: php, plugins, dreamweaver

I've been looking for a while now for a plugin for Dreamweaver that automatically adds code-collapse markers for PHP editing, and I haven't come up with anything.

I wonder if anyone has found anything of the sort, or if it is possible for me to write my own plugin? I've never done one for Dreamweaver before, so I don't know if something like this is doable.

Comment: No, I have looked for it, but there isn't any plugin, unfortunately.

Comment: Terrible finding friend. Perhaps I should look into writing one myself and distributing it. Seems like there is a high demand for this.

Answer (score 0):

Dreamweaver already has that feature. Simply select the lines you wanna collapse and press `-` sign at left (on line numbers) it will collapse that area.

Comment: Thank you but I meant something that doesn't require that I re-select my code block after I've made edits. Something that Automatically marks code blocks.

Comment: I would up your answer but sadly it was not an 'answer' to the question I asked. Sorry m8.